# val arrayListOf() in companion object returns an invalid value

Tags: android, kotlin

I have code:

```
class DrawerViewModel : ViewModel() {

    fun updateDrawerProfiles() {
        val example = DrawerUtils.exampleProfile
        example.add(  DrawerAccount(3, "NEW Test") )
        setDrawerProfiles(example)
    }

}
```

```
class DrawerUtils {

    companion object {

        val exampleProfile = arrayListOf(
            DrawerAccount(1, "Facebook"),
            DrawerAccount(2, "Google")
        )

    }
}
```

[Run Example Code](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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
)

when I run several times function updateDrawerProfiles return vailid size of list.
RUN x3 **updateDrawerProfiles**() | OUTPUT:
3
4
5

it should be 
3
3
3.

When I move function updateDrawerProfiles outsiede companion object - it is ok. 
Why is it like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it should be 3 3 3.

Wrong.

The `DrawerUtils` companion is a Singleton. Create it once and the object keeps existing. You're adding new values to `exampleProfile` 3 times, so it makes sense for the size to grow to 3, then 4 and then 5.

Please do some reading on this topic https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/kotlin-for-py/objects-and-companion-objects.html

Comment: I know it is Singleton but for me it is weird. when I look at the code I see get the value from DrawerUtils.exampleProfile to example then add item.So, more Kotlin :)

Comment: When you call `DrawerUtils.exampleProfile` you aren't creating a new ArrayList, but instead obtain the reference to that ArrayList within the `DrawerUtils` Singleton.

Comment: ok. Now I understand. the "val" fooled me. I change the content of the arraylist, not the variable. is it right?

Comment: val means you can't re-assign a new arraylist to the variable. It still means you can add entries to the list